# Get Special Price products collections programmatically

Tags: magento-1.7, product, special-price

I have created some products in magento admin panel by giving **Special Price**.

So how can I get only the **Special Price Products** collection programmatically in Observer.php?

I have created custom module to get all special price products.

Any help are welcome with thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To add a filter for `special_from_date` you can add this after the code above

```
$now = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate();
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('or'=> array(
    0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $now),
    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
), 'left')
```

Comment: I need to filter the products only based on Special Price. Get the products if only the Special Price field have value.